# Optimal cost constructing a square-based rectangular prism

Tags: derivatives, optimization

You have to construct a square-based rectangular prism where the cost is 2 cents per square centimeter for the base and top, and 1 cent per square centimeter for the sides.

The height cannot be greater than 30cm and the Volume holds 2 Litres. Use the constraints on carton capacity to express cost as a single variable and find the range of this chosen variable, aiming to minimise cost.

Now I assume

$$C = 2(2l^2) + 1(4h)$$

with the constraints

$$h < 30\>\>\>\text{and}\>\>\>V = l^2*h = 2000$$

We could sub in $h = V/l^2$. But I'm really confused what to do after this point or if this is even correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You have to enclose the MathJax in `$` signs for the formatting to work.

Comment: Your cost equation is missing a factor $l$ in the second term as all the sides have area $hl$.  Substituting in is the correct approach because you get the cost as a function of one variable.  Then to find a minimum, differentiate and set to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total cost equation is given by

$$ C = 2\times 2l^2 +1\times 4lh $$

with the volume $l^2h=2000$.

Substitute the height $h=2000/l^2$ in the cost with $l$ to express the cost with a single variable $l$,

$$ C(l) = 4l^2 + \frac{8000}{l} $$

Then, take the derivative and set it to zero $dC/dl=0$,

$$8l-\frac{8000}{l^2}=0$$

which gives

$$l = 10$$

The corresponding height is then

$$h=20$$

Thus, to minimize the cost, the dimension is 10cm wide for the square and 20cm in height.

---

Here are the plots for both $C(l)$ and $dC/dl$,

[image]

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. So if l is the chosen variable, what does it mean by the range allowed? And if I was to find the global minimum by checking for stationary and endpoints, would I just use the derivative formula and sketch it?

Comment: The range allow for $l$ is determined by $h=V/l^2\le 30$, which implies $l\ge = \sqrt{200/3}$. You could sketch it that way.

Comment: I tried to sketch the initial cost function, but it goes into a negative y value, which doesn't seem plausible for cost

Comment: Added both plots.